# Slick - What if database does not contain result

Tags: scala, rest, slick, spray

I am trying to build a simple RESTful service that performs CRUD operations on a database and returns JSON. I have a service adhering to an API like this

```
GET mydomain.com/predictions/some%20string
```

I use a DAO which contains the following method that I have created to retrieve the associated prediction:

```
def getPrediction(rawText: String): Prediction = {
  val predictionAction = predictions.filter{_.rawText === rawText}.result
  val header = predictionAction.head
  val f = db.run(header)
  f.onComplete{case pred => pred}
  throw new Exception("Oops")
}
```

However, this can't be right, so I started reading about `Option`. I changed my code accordingly:

```
def getPrediction(rawText: String): Option[Prediction] = {
  val predictionAction = predictions.filter{_.rawText === rawText}.result
  val header = predictionAction.headOption
  val f = db.run(header)
  f.onSuccess{case pred => pred}
  None
}
```

This still doesn't feel quite right. What is the best way to invoke these filters, return the results, and handle any uncertainty?

Comment: Which version of slick?

Comment: @marcospereira `3.1.1`. I think I figured it out by adding `return Some(red)` and `return None`. I read a little more about `Option` and am using `.isEmpty` to decide what to do. I'm still curious about the best way to use `Slick` though as the documentation seems pretty ambiguous. For example, there is also the `DBIO` sequences. Not sure which is best to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to rewrite your code is like this:

```
def getPrediction(rawText: String): Future[Option[Prediction]] = {
  db.run(users.filter(_.rawText === rawText).result.headOption)
}
```

In other words, return a `Future` instead of the plain result. This way, the database actions will execute asynchronously, which is the preferred way for both Play and Akka.

The client code will then work with the `Future`. Per instance, a Play action would be like:

```
def prediction = Action.async {
  predictionDao.getPrediction("some string").map { pred =>
    Ok(views.html.predictions.show(pred))
  }.recover {
    case ex =>
      logger.error(ex)
      BadRequest()
  }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion really cleaned up my dao api, so thanks. I am actually using Spray, so I had some trouble with `onComplete`, but I finally got it working and learned a lot about Futures in the process. Also, should `_.rawText ==` be `_.rawText ===`?

Comment: @BrianVanover made small corrections based on your comment. Also, feel free to edit the answer and add how to use the dao method with Spray. ;-)

Comment: @marcospereira Why don't you just write `db.run(users.filter(_.rawText === rawText).result.headOption)`?

Comment: @MustafaSimav yep. writing too fast to notice this. Thanks!